# Could not remove special charcters from string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove all special characters from string using Javascript but its unable to remove. Please find my code below.

```
function checkString(){
      var sourceString='a|"bc!@£de^&$f g';
      var outString = sourceString.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()|+\-=?;:'",<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
      console.log('sourcestring',outString);
}
```

Here I could not get the expected output. I am getting this `abcÂ£def g` in console. Here I need to remove all special characters. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You might consider using a character set *whitelist* instead, if you can, otherwise you'll have lots and lots of characters to specify. (is a whitelist an option?)

Comment: It's because you are not removing the pound sign. Which leads to what @CertainPerformance said - if you are trying to blacklist, you need to keep adding more and more symbols, and it becomes unfeasable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex:

```js
var sourceString='a|"bc!@£de^&$f g';

console.log("Before: " + sourceString);
sourceString = sourceString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
console.log("After: " + sourceString);
```

**It essentially removes everything but alphabet and numbers (and spaces).**

Answer (score 0):

Remove every thing except numbers and letters.

```js
var sourceString='a|"bc!@£de^&$f g';
     // var outString = sourceString.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()|+\-=?;:'",<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
   var outString = sourceString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
      console.log('sourcestring',outString);
```

Comment: Same answer as above